# How to get an output from stored procedure when condition is comparing string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_City_SelectByPK]
@CityName varchar
AS
SELECT [dbo].[City].[CityName], [dbo].[City].[State]
FROM [dbo].[City]
WHERE [dbo].[City].[CityName] = @CityName
```

Primary key is CityName.
I am trying to get CityName and State as output from the Stored procedure but I am not getting any output value in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use string types in SQL Server without a length parameter.  The default varies by context.  And in this context, it is 1.

So, try something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_City_SelectByPK] (
    @CityName varchar(255)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [dbo].[City].[CityName], [dbo].[City].[State]
    FROM [dbo].[City]
    WHERE [dbo].[City].[CityName] = @CityName;
END;
```

Notes:

- I also strongly recommend that the body always be enclosed in a `BEGIN`/`END` block.  This makes it clear where the stored procedure ends.
- For this type of operation, you might consider a user-defined function.

Comment: `BEGIN/END` *don't* make it clear, it confuses people into thinking that everything after `END` is not part of the stored procedure, this is simply not true as the whole batch is part of the procedure. This is why you often see problems with `CREATE PROC someProc AS BEGIN ...... END EXEC someProc`. You are much better off just putting `GO` at the end of the procedure

Answer (score 0):

the @CityName parameter is varchar without size wich meen it is varchar(1) you need to set its size like varchar(50):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_City_SelectByPK]
@CityName varchar(50)
AS
SELECT [dbo].[City].[CityName], [dbo].[City].[State]
FROM [dbo].[City]
WHERE [dbo].[City].[CityName] = @CityName
```